# Filtering a distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, data-science

so I'm working on an optimization problem and wanted to create a function that, given a client X will give me the cities under a certain distance radius. [image]

Say you pick client A. I want to get a list of all the clients that are less than 2 miles away. If you see the image you can see that I should get a list that looks like this:
[A,B,C,D,E,F,I,M,O]
which are the cities that meet the criteria.
Thanks!

I don't know how to filter columns by row condition, and get a list of the column headers that meet the criteria

Answer (score 0):

I get that "Cliente" is both index and columns of the dataframe

```
df.loc[(df.loc[:, "A"] < 2) & (df.index != "A")].index.to_list()
```

> or by columns

```
df.loc["A", df["A"] < 2].drop("A").index.to_list()
```

> If you want to leave "A" (the initial client)

```
# by index
df.loc[df.loc[:, "A"] < 2].index.to_list()

# by columns
df.loc["A", df["A"] < 2].index.to_list()
```